# MongoDB: How to load collection with nested array in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have collection called "servers" with following documents.

```
{
    name: "West",
    ip: "123.123.123.123",
    channels:
    [
        {
            name: "English",
            port: "1234",
            status: "0"
        },
        {
            name: "Spanish",
            port: "1235",
            status: "0"
        },
        {
            name: "German",
            port: "1236",
            status: "0"
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: "East",
    ip: "122.122.122.122",
    channels:
    [
        {
            name: "English",
            port: "1234",
            status: "0"
        },
        {
            name: "French",
            port: "1235",
            status: "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I select that from MongoDB using C# using structures?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want all items you can use follwoing code:

```
var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost:27020");
var database = server.GetDatabase("someDb");

var servers = database.GetCollection<ServerItem>("servers");
servers.FindAllAs<ServerItem>();
```

But if you want for example all documents with name = west, than you can:

```
collection.FindAs<ServerItem>(Query.EQ("name","west"));
```

ServerItem:

```
 public class ServerItem
 {
   public string name { get; set; }

   public string ip { get; set; }

   public List<Channel> channels { get; set; }
 } 

 public class Channel
 {
   public string name { get; set; }

   public int port { get; set; }

   public int status { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: That would work with sturct too, right? Not only class, but struct as well.

Comment: Hey @AndrewOrsich would you mind looking at my question. It is very similar to the answer you provided above. I just cannot seem to make it work still. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089566/how-to-match-array-within-array-in-json-file-with-c-sharp-controller-code

Comment: how to find channels.name="English"?