# How to match array within array in json file with c# controller code?

Tags: c#, .net, json, mongodb

I am trying to match my model code with the same structure as my json file. The json file has jsonArray which works fine as ReportList if accountlist (another array inside array items) did not exist.

Now I am trying to make it work with account list. So I created MyListType which matches the structure of accountlist in the json file.

Unfortunately, I am getting an error saying accountlist in json file does not match any field or property of Report class. (which I think should be matching with MyListType)
Please help me to resolve this error. Thanks in advance.

The Model code

```
public class Report
{
 public Object _id { get; set; }
 public string username { get; set; }
 public List<MyListType> accountlist{get; set;}
}
public class MyListType
{
 public string address1 {get; set;}
 public string address2 {get; set;}
}
```

Partial Controller Code

```
MongoCollection<Report> collection = Context.Database.GetCollection<Report>("report");
var ReportList = new List<Report>();
//Right below I get: Errors out here Element 'accountlist' does not match any field or //property of class MyProject.Models.Report.
foreach (Report doc in collection.FindAll()) 
{
 ReportList.Add(doc);
}
```

report collection

```
{
   "username" : "doodle",
   "accountlist" : [
                      {"address1": "abc st", "address2": "efg st"},
                      {"address1": "hijk st", "address2": "mno st"}
                   ]
  }

  {
   "username" : "doodle2",
   "accountlist" : [
                      {"address1": "abc st", "address2": "efg st"},
                      {"address1": "hijk st", "address2": "mno st"}
                   ]
  }
```

Comment: so after much digging I did find similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135576/mongodb-how-to-load-collection-with-nested-array-in-c From this post I learned that I need to change my FindAll() to FindAllAs<Report>() in the foreach loop in my code. But I am still getting the error though. I know I am getting close.

Comment: Changing FindAll() to FindAllAs<Report>() did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at my code more, I found out that the problem was that I used different name for my field "accountslist" vs the one in the collection accountlist. The field names in the class that represents collection needs to match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to register this these types in the ClassMap

```
  if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(Report))) BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Report>(cm => { cm.AutoMap(); cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true); });

  if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(MyListType))) BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyListType>(cm => { cm.AutoMap(); cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true); });

  var reports = _collection.FindAllAs<Report>().ToList();
```